# Keras: Multiple inputs and Multiple ouputs for fit_generator using flow_from_directory

Tags: keras

Multi task learning Model accepts three inputs. I am using keras data generator. Is it possible to pass three data generator to model.fit_generator function ?.

### Problem Definition

I am working a classification problem. The dataset i am using is Painters by number, a competition hosted by kaggle . The task is to identify painter,style and genre given paintings.

I have developed individual models to perform each task. Now, i would like to incorporate multi task learning, see if it outperforms individual models.

```python
 Model                       No of classes (Softmax)
------                     ------------------------                                   
 Model predicting painter         8
 given paintings

 Model predicting style           10
 given paintings      


 Model predicting genre           23
 given paintings
```

The above table details the individual models and the no of output classes for each model.

Now, i want to do multi task learning , so I came up with below simple architecture
[Multi Task Learning Architecture](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/28932/is-it-possible-to-pass-multiple-data-generators-for-multiple-inputs-to-model-fit)

```python
 style   = Input(shape=(64,64,3))
 genre   = Input(shape=(64,64,3))
 painter = Input(shape=(64,64,3))


 shared_conv = Convolution2D(
            filters = 5,# 5 feature maps
            kernel_size = (5,5),
            strides = 1) 

 shared_conv_layer_A = shared_conv(style)
 shared_conv_layer_B = shared_conv(genre)
 shared_conv_layer_C = shared_conv(painter)

 merged_layer = keras.layers.concatenate([shared_conv_layer_A,shared_conv_layer_B,shared_conv_layer_C],axis=-1)

 pooling = MaxPooling2D(
        pool_size = (2,2),
        strides = 2
      )(merged_layer)

 dense = Flatten()(pooling)

 out_style = Dense(
        no_classes_style, 
        kernel_initializer=glorot_normal(seed=seed_val), 
        bias_initializer = 'zero', 
        kernel_regularizer = l2(l=0.0001),
        activation = 'softmax',
    )(dense)

 out_genre = Dense(
        no_classes_genre, 
        kernel_initializer=glorot_normal(seed=seed_val), 
        bias_initializer = 'zero', 
        kernel_regularizer = l2(l=0.0001),
        activation = 'softmax',
    )(dense)

 out_painter = Dense(
        no_classes_painter, 
        kernel_initializer=glorot_normal(seed=seed_val), 
        bias_initializer = 'zero', 
        kernel_regularizer = l2(l=0.0001),
        activation = 'softmax',
    )(dense)


 multi_tasking_model = Model(inputs=[style,genre,painter],outputs=[out_style,out_genre,out_painter])
 multi_tasking_model.summary()


 multi_tasking_model.compile(
   loss = 'categorical_crossentropy', 
   optimizer=Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=0.00000001 ),
   metrics=['accuracy'] 
 )
```

> Now i want to pass three keras image data generators. So, i came up with a custom data generator

```python
 def create_data_generator(style_generator,genre_generator,painter_generator):
    # Input
    _style_generator = style_generator[0]
    _genre_generator = genre_generator[0]
    _painter_generator = painter_generator[0]

   # Label
   _lstyle_generator = style_generator[1]
   _lgenre_generator = genre_generator[1]
   _lpainter_generator = painter_generator[1]

return [_style_generator,_genre_generator,_painter_generator],[_lstyle_generator,_genre_generator,_painter_generator]

train_mulitle_data_generator = create_data_generator(trainStyleDataGenerator,trainGenreDataGenerator,trainPainterDataGenerator) 
valid_mulitle_data_generator = create_data_generator(validationStyleDataGenerator,validationGenreDataGenerator,validationPainterDataGenerator)




history = multi_tasking_model.fit_generator(
     generator = train_mulitle_data_generator,
     steps_per_epoch= len(train_mulitle_data_generator),
     epochs = no_epoch,
     validation_data = valid_mulitle_data_generator,
 )
```

> The error i encountered

```python
   'tuple' object has no attribute 'ndim'
```

> Is there any alternative way to pass multiple inputs and multiple outputs. Any suggestions or tips would be greatly helpful please ?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the moment `create_data_generator` does not define a generator. Try this:

```
def create_data_generator(style_generator,genre_generator,painter_generator):

    while(True):
        _style_generator, _lstyle_generator = next(style_generator)
        _genre_generator, _lgenre_generator = next(genre_generator)
        _painter_generator, _lpainter_generator = next(painter_generator)

        yield [_style_generator,_genre_generator,_painter_generator], [_lstyle_generator,_genre_generator,_painter_generator]
```